# sort files from directory based on unique time stamp and group them

Tags: linux, bash, algorithm, shell, sorting

I want to get the list of files from a directory and group them in an array or variable based on unique time stamp ( ls -ltr month , day ) using bash. this time stamp is 2-3 columns in range.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This is a one-liner don't know if is exactly what you are asking for:

```
array=($(ls -ltr  | awk -v x=9 '{print $x}'))
```

It will create an array with the output of `ls -ltr` of the files

To print contents of the array:

```
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}"
```

But is also worth checking this "[Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)"

Comment: This lists all ls -ltr output in a single array. However, I want to group them in different arrays based on the unique time stamp. This time-stamp contains ( Month day columns from ls -ltr ).

Comment: You asked for the output of the solution to be saved in an array, now that the answer is here you change your mind :)